# How can I use MinGW Makefiles with CMake in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, makefile, mingw

I am trying to cross-compile onto Windows from Linux with CMake. I have MinGW32 installed, but when I try to run CMake with MinGW Makefiles as the generator, I get:

CMake Error: Could not create named generator MinGW Makefiles

It then shows me a list of generators it has, but MinGW Makefiles is not one of them.

How can I run CMake with MinGW32 Makefiles on Linux?

Comment: You should probably not use that generator, since you are using Linux's Make utility to build your code instead of a MinGW version of Make.  Did you try omitting the generator argument so that it just uses the default generator instead?

Comment: I am trying to cross compile, so the binary I get needs to work on Windows.

Comment: There is a distinction between using Linux Makefiles and using a compiler for Linux.  Try using Linux Makefiles along with the MinGW C compiler.  CMake has standard options you can use to specify the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

mingw for linux has option

```
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/usr/share/mingw/toolchain-mingw{32|64}.cmake
```

and generates right Makefile.